# Process managing in C: sending data to the parent process

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm doing a program for an Operative Sytems class, and I need a good way to pass an integer from the child process to its parent, preferably without using pipes.

After a bit of try and error, I got something like this to do the job:

```
pid_t pid_son;
int status;

if( (pid_son = fork()) >= 0) {
    if(pid_son == 0) {
        int result = 0;
        // Make some arithmetic
         exit(result);   
    }
    else {
        while(pid_son != wait(&status));
        printf("The result is %d\n",result);
    }
}
```

But that does not look "right" to me (exit is supposed to return the process' exit status for error handling, not a random integer). Is there a cleaner way to "send" the result to the parent process without using this trick?

Comment: Why can't you use pipes? See also the Linux specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)

Comment: You could send an email?

Comment: This "trick" will only let you communicate 256 different values on most systems.

Comment: "preferably without using pipes." There's about a zillion ways to make it happen, but using pipes is probably the most simple and clean one.

Comment: @KerrekSB I've just tested the "exit" trick and I've found out that the results you obtain this way are indeed limited to 256. 
It's also interesting that the result returned by "exit" is multiplied by 256 when I grab "status".

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) - it explains quite well what pipes are.

Comment: And learn to read man pages (on Unbuntu, `sudo aptitude install man manpages-dev` then type `man man`). Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) etc...

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned this, perhaps it's the way the question was asked. The obvious response is why are you forking a process to do work in parallel instead of just using a thread? With threads, you just share the same memory space between parent and child - there's no pipes or popen calls to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to read the child process's standard output.

In C, that involves pipes :)

It isn't as terrible as you think. Look at the standard examples for using [popen](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html).

EDIT: if it's a fork of your own process, not a fork-exec, the answer is still pipes.

Comment: `popen`, however, has the disadvantage of tying the pipe to standard output of the child process, so it cannot use stdout for anything else then.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid pipes and are willing to use more obscure mechanisms, I suggest you look into `sigqueue(3)`, which you can use to send an integer to another process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I'll go ahead and use pipes. I'll probably have to deal with them later, so I better get familiar with them now.

Answer (score 1):

Shared memory could also work here.

Look up [shmget](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) and [shmat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) functions